# tr command with special character

Tags: bash

I am trying to substitute `"<br>"` to "\n" but do not find how use the <> with tr. Any idea to do this command work:

```
echo "HTML example<br>Print new line<br>please<br>not work" | tr "<br>" "\n"
```

edit

The **FatalError** answer do not work for my OSX Lion. I don't know why, but this simple `sed` command do not make new line, it return only

```
HTML examplenPrint new linenpleasennot work
```

I am using GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11). 
Any other idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tr` is for mapping chars to other chars. For this task I'd suggest using `sed`:

```
echo "HTML example<br>Print new line<br>please<br>not work" | sed -e 's/<br>/\n/g'
```

This tells `sed` to substitute every instance of `<br>` with a newline char.

**Edit**

If you have problem, because the /\ in sed, this will solve the problem

```
echo "HTML example<br>Print new line<br>please<br>not work" | sed -e "s/<br>/\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/g"
```

Comment: Been in your shoes all too often ;).

Comment: I already try to use sed, but not work for mac OSX Lion with GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)

Comment: @Rodrigo sed is not part of bash (separate program), so it matters that it's Mac OS, but not which version of bash. That said -- the right solution is to fix your sed command, not to use tr.

Comment: @Rodrigo Probably you don't have GNU `sed`, but rather the BSD `sed`. In this case, the `-e` might be important (it's not required for GNU). But I'm a little rusty.  Can you show the results you see?

Comment: It just show: `HTML examplenPrint new linenpleasennot work`. But I found the answer (I edit FatalError answer, can you see), little more complex but work. The problem was because the command have a /\ string

Comment: BSD `sed` does not understand `\n` and will not allow a literal newline on the right hand of a substitution without it being escaped. If your shell is `bash` you can use  `echo 'HTML example<br>Print new line<br>please<br>not work' | sed 's/<br>/\'$'\n''/g'` for `sed`s liek this.

Comment: I could not do inverse, convert \n to br